# Trigger at First Business Day of Month

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to run a pipeline that starts at the first business day of month. It can be set in a trigger or in an if condition to run all the activities at this day.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an if condition activity with the following code:

```
@or(and(equals(dayOfMonth(utcnow()),1), and(greater(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),0),less(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),6))),or(and(equals(dayOfMonth(utcnow()),2), equals(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),1)),and(equals(dayOfMonth(utcnow()),3), equals(dayOfWeek(utcnow()),1))))
```